Sequelize Many to Many relation with an unique field
I have role and permission model. They have a many to many relation, but permission model´s primary key is composed by two fields, also, permission model has id field that is just unique and not a key. The problem is Sequelize is trying to relate permission and rolePermission model by name because it is the first primary key. Look the code
Role model:
const Role = db.define(
  "role",
  {
    id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: sequelize.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);


Permission Model:
const Permission = db.define(
  "permission",
  {
    id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: false,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: sequelize.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    option: {
      type: sequelize.ENUM("view", "add", "edit", "delete"),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  },
  { freezeTableName: true, updatedAt: false }
);

Relation Model:
const RolePermission = db.define(
  "rolepermission",
  {
    roleId: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    permissionId: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      
    },
  },
  { freezeTableName: true, updatedAt: false }
);

Relation specify:
roleModel.belongsToMany(permissionModel, {
  
  through: "rolepermission",
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "roleId",
  otherKey: "permissionId",
});

permissionModel.belongsToMany(roleModel, {
  through: "rolepermission",
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "permissionId",
  otherKey: "roleId",
});

I try this:
const userData = await userModel.findOne({
      where: { id: id },
      include: [
        {
          model: roleModel,
          include: [
            {
              model: permissionModel,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });

The problem is in the query, it detects name as the first permission primary key, so it tried to do:
INNER JOIN permission AS roles->permissions ON roles->permissions.name = roles->permissions->rolepermission.permissionId) ON roles.id = roles->permissions->rolepermission.roleId WHERE user.id = 3;
The mistake is in the comparison (roles->permissions.name = roles->permissions->rolepermission.permissionId) when i need to look up after id field(roles->permissions.id = roles->permissions->rolepermission.permissionId)
I tried a lot of things including
const userData = await userModel.findOne({
      where: { id: id },
      include: [
        {
          model: roleModel,
          through: {
            attributes: [], // Don't include RolePermission attributes
          },
          include: [
            {
              model: permissionModel,
              through: {
                attributes: [], // Don't include RolePermission attributes
              },
              foreignKey: "id", // Specify the foreign key of Permission model
              targetKey: "permissionId", // Specify the target key to associate with roleId in junction table
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });

but it continues to thinks the relation is with permission.name
I need something that tells to sequelize that the relation is through permission.id
When i set primaryKey: True in the permission field it works perfectly
